# inserir dados em uma tabela com PDO

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, pdo

Olá, estou fazendo o meu primeiro codigo em PDO mas quando estou executando o codigo, ele me traz um erro que não faço ideia do que seja, agradeço a ajuda desde já.

```
<?php
session_start();
include('conn_prod.php');

$SendCadImg = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'SendCadImg', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  if ($SendCadImg) {
    # code...
    $id_nec = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'tema', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $tema = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'tema', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $nome_img = $_FILES['arquivo']['name'];

    $result_img = "INSERT INTO necessaires (id_nec, tema, imagem, data) VALUES (:id_nec, :tema, :nome_img, NOW())";
    $insert_img = $conn_prod->prepare($result_img);
    $insert_img->bindParam(':id_nec', $id_nec);
    $insert_img->bindParam(':tema', $tema);
    $insert_img->bindParam(':imagem', $nome_img);

      $insert_img->execute();          

  } else {
      $_SESSION['img'] = "<p>Erro ao salvar oo dados</p>";
      header("Location: produtos.php");
  }
?>
```

Comment: E qual é o erro?

Comment: Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\Painel de controle\processa_prod.php on line 18

Comment: Não existe o parâmetro ":imagem", e sim ":nome_img". vê se isso resolve.

Comment: era um erro tão besta que deixei escapar kkk funcionou sim muito obrigado.